# Is there any way to install xap on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I successfully run Windows Phone 8 (Flash.vhd from SDK) on VirtualBox, but I cannot find a way how to install xap on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAP deploy tool [XapDeploy.exe], located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment`